# Function '' doesn't return a value on all code paths

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am receiving a return value error and I don't know what I've done wrong.
I don't know where to return a value can someone help me?

```
Function bot_loop()
            Dim pointer_to_localplayer As Integer
            Dim pointer_to_incross_player As Integer
            Dim player_index_incross As Integer
            Dim my_team As Integer
            Dim incross_team As Integer
            While (Not exit_thread)
                If triggeron = True Then
                    ReadProcessMemory(ffa_process(0).Handle, client_dll_base + LocalPlayer_offset, pointer_to_localplayer, 4, 0)
                    ReadProcessMemory(ffa_process(0).Handle, pointer_to_localplayer + InCross_offset, player_index_incross, 4, 0)
                    If player_index_incross > 0 And player_index_incross < 65 Then
                        ReadProcessMemory(ffa_process(0).Handle, pointer_to_localplayer + Team_offset, my_team, 4, 0)
                        ReadProcessMemory(ffa_process(0).Handle, client_dll_base + EntityList_offset + ((player_index_incross - 1) * &H10), pointer_to_incross_player, 4, 0)
                        ReadProcessMemory(ffa_process(0).Handle, pointer_to_incross_player + Team_offset, incross_team, 4, 0)
                        If Not my_team = incross_team Then
                            mouse_event(&H2, 0, 0, 0, 1)
                            Threading.Thread.Sleep(15)
                            mouse_event(&H4, 0, 0, 0, 1)
                            Threading.Thread.Sleep(10)
                        End If
                    End If
                Else
                End If
                Threading.Thread.Sleep(10)
            End While
        End Function
```

Comment: What do you want to return with this?

Comment: @OneFineDay I want it to stop the loop

Comment: That is not what a function does.

Comment: It is obvious this is not your code. What your asking for it trivial as compared to the complexity of the presented code. Stop grabbing code from the internet if you have no idea what it does.

Comment: Please take a moment to review this *carefully*: [Ask].  Please use complete words: idk what 'idk' means

Comment: Do what @slugster said or right before End Function put: Return Nothing

Answer (score 5):

You have a `Function`, which by definition is supposed to return a value. If you don't care about returning any value then change it to a `Sub`.